# writing a 3d array of data to file

Tags: file, serialization, filestructure

What are some common formats for writing 3d data arrays to (txt) file?

(if I have to do this, I would rather use a format that someone else can follow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a pre-existing standard for something like this, but how about:

```
[
  [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6]
  ],
  [
    [7,8,9],
    [10,11,12]
  ]
],
[
  [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6]
  ],
  [
    [7,8,9],
    [10,11,12]
  ]
]
```

It's easy to read but if you want to flatten it it would look like this:

[
  [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6]
  ],
  [
    [7,8,9],
    [10,11,12]
  ]
],
[
  [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6]
  ],
  [
    [7,8,9],
    [10,11,12]
  ]
]

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't come up with a standard format, however here is a tutorial:

http://ww.functionx.com/csharp/Lesson23.htm

it uses something that could be reduced to the following:

```
double[2, 3, 5]:
[
        [
            [  12.44, 525.38,  -6.28,  2448.32, 632.04 ],
            [-378.05,  48.14, 634.18,   762.48,  83.02 ],
            [  64.92,  -7.44,  86.74,  -534.60, 386.73 ]
        ],
        [
            [  48.02, 120.44,   38.62,  526.82, 1704.62 ],
            [  56.85, 105.48,  363.31,  172.62,  128.48 ],
            [  906.68, 47.12, -166.07, 4444.26,  408.62 ]
        ]
]
```

Correct me if I am wrong but basically you would just create an array of arrays to accomodate however many dimensions you need.

Comment: Well, if both you and @FrustratedWithFormsDes came up with the same thing it is probably worthwhile. It still seems a little clunky to me, but I cant think of anything else.